# Need to add order on ids on the basis of timestamp

Tags: pyspark

[image]

Desired Outcome

[image]

Tried Everthing group by and condition but not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with windowing function, like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

window = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("timestamp")

df.withColumn("order", row_number().over(window)).show()

+----+---------+-----+
|user|timestamp|order|
+----+---------+-----+
| 111|    12:00|    1|
| 111|    12:30|    2|
| 111|    12:45|    3|
| 112|    12:00|    1|
| 112|    12:30|    2|
| 112|    12:45|    3|
| 113|    12:00|    1|
| 113|    12:30|    2|
| 113|    12:45|    3|
+----+---------+-----+
```